# Concerning memory efficiency of closure in JS

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning closure in JS and also I found out that closure is useful in terms of memory efficiency. Say, we have the below code using closure:

```
function heavyDuty()
{
const hugeArray = new Array(1000000).fill('item');

return function(index){
return hugeArray[index];
}
}

const getHugeArray = heavyDuty();
getHugeArray[577];
```

As you can see in the above code, function heavyDuty returns another function helping us achieve memory efficiency. But what confuses me is that what if we do not return another function but return array itself. For example,

```
function heavyDuty()
{
const hugeArray = new Array(1000000).fill('item');
return hugeArray;
}

const getHugeArray = heavyDuty();
getHugeArray[577];
```

The question is will the above example where we return array itself help us achieve memory efficiency like if we return function.

Comment: You still have the same array in memory either way. I'm not sure what you would consider more efficient.

Comment: *"...and also I found out that closure is useful in terms of memory efficiency."* No, not really.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Good day Mr.Crowder, thanks for your kind comments. Is it really true that closure does not help us attain memory efficiency? if so, when it is best to use closure in JS. Just your brief explanation would be highly appreciated:).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, please Mr.Crowder I really need your help

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's the reverse, closures could be less efficient in terms of speed and memory:

> It is unwise to unnecessarily create functions within other functions
>   if closures are not needed for a particular task, as it will
>   negatively affect script performance both in terms of processing speed
>   and memory consumption.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

That's because methods will be reassigned for every object creation. While you could avoid that with the object's prototype

Comment: thank you for your answer, please can you tell me, from your experience, in what situation you understand that you need to use Closure. Please I really need your help

Comment: check out the link I gave you. It's the official documentation and has a brief explanation about closures.