# Caching without returning function

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning closure. Then I wonder what if instead of returning a function so as to cache the returned value, I decided to return the value itself. Is it true that with the below code we can achieve caching of returned value.

```
function heavyDuty(){
const hugeArray = new Array(1000000).fill("item");
return hugeArray;
}

let getHugeArray = heavyDuty();
getHugeArray[400]
getHugeArray[400]
```

Comment: where is the difference of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512860/concerning-memory-efficiency-of-closure-in-js) of yesterday?

Comment: @NinaScholz, unfortunately, I did not get necessary help in my yesterday question thus I am asking again with the hope that I could get enough help

Comment: i have a problem to understand what you are asking. the function returns an array. i see neither a cache nor a closure. for me, if you need only a single value, take this value. if you need the array later or someotherinformation, like other values/indices, take the array.

Comment: @NinaScholz, first of all, thank you that spare your time to help me:). No, I mean, according to my research closure is helpful when we want to achieve memory efficiency thanks to caching a value. To do that we need to return a function but what if we do not return a function and return a value. So, you mean in the above code example, there is no caching, I mean, if we execute getHugeArray several times, there is no caching?

Comment: Are you referring to memoization? Memoization ensures only one instance is computed when the function is invoked, regardless of the number of times it's called. In your situation, `heavyDuty` will recompute and create a new array from every invocation. Your example is not caching

Comment: @Andrew, thanks Andrew for your kind help

Comment: @Andrew, sorry Andrew just my last question is it true that closure's main benefit is memoization and encapsulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caching the computed value requires you to store the value internally within another `function` that `return`s that pre-computed value every time it is invoked. Here is a basic example of caching `heavyDuty` using a caching function.

```js
function heavyDuty(){
    const hugeArray = new Array(1000000).fill("item");
    return hugeArray;
}

function once(fn) {
    const computed = fn()
    return () => computed
}

const cachedHeavyDuty = once(heavyDuty)

console.log('uncached equality check:', heavyDuty() === heavyDuty())

console.log('cached equality check:', cachedHeavyDuty() === cachedHeavyDuty())
```

Edit: Closures have multiple utilities. Closures are simply a programming concept. They can be leveraged in many different ways. One of them being the implementation of a memoization/caching function